# Make the markers on the LineChart transparent. javafx

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm displaying data on a LineChart. With GUI I am adding new data and I have a need to add new data series. I also need the new data series to have transparent symbols.
If this is not done, then the following picture will turn out:

[image: Example showing bold lines are made up of markers]

The data series are added dynamically, and I don't know if it's possible to somehow apply css styles to these data series.

The only solution that I have come up with so far is to create a new CSS file every time I change the chart, in which the transparency property will be written for each color:

```
/* Remove data series points */
.default-color0.chart-line-symbol {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
/* Remove data series lines */
.default-color1.chart-series-line {
    -fx-stroke: transparent;
}
/* Remove data series lines */
.default-color2.chart-series-line {
    -fx-stroke: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pure css, you can add `.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: transparent; }` and after that you can modify the stroke of the first series to its original color with `.default-color0.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: CHART_COLOR_1; }`.

```
.chart-series-line {
    -fx-stroke: transparent;
}

.default-color0.chart-series-line {
    -fx-stroke: CHART_COLOR_1;
}

.default-color0.chart-line-symbol {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a listener to the chart series `ObservableList` programmatically. When a change notification is received, you can iterate over the series and find the line `Node` using the lookup css selector `.chart-series-line`. Finally, you can set the node style `-fx-stroke: transparent;`.

Assuming that the first series (`series1`) always stays in the chart, here's a sample code:

```
chart.getData().add(series1);

chart.getData().addListener((ListChangeListener<XYChart.Series>) c -> {
    while (c.next()) {
        if (c.wasAdded()) {
            c.getAddedSubList().stream()
                    .map(series -> series.getNode().lookup(".chart-series-line"))
                    .forEach(node -> node.setStyle("-fx-stroke: transparent;"));
        }
    }
});
```